# Gif image loads on local host but not on hosted server/live site

Tags: php, html, laravel-5, laravel-blade

I am working on a laravel project. I want to show an animated gif on my webpage. The gif image is displaying fine at localhost but at live site, image is displayed broken. I have tried different gif images but still no success. and strange thing i can load jpg or png image from same folder with live site, but gif image does not work. There is no spelling mistake and gif file is present at server.

`<img width="100px" height="100px" src="{{ URL::to('/') }}/storage/images/anim.gif">`

[information from chrome network tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tbxiw.jpg)

In picture above is information from chrome network tab

Comment: Are .gif images perhaps blocked by your web server?

Comment: It's clear that the URL points to an HTML document. You haven't really given us anything to go on to explain why or what that HTML document contains

Comment: https://buzdy.com/storage/images/anim.gif ... nothing? Is your .gif image broken?

Comment: probably you have a .htaccess[or in your webserver config] file, that block .gif files

Comment: all the other content of HTML document is irrelevant. only problem is image not loading and gif file is not broken as it works fine at localhost.

Comment: @saeid That is good hint provided. thanks for that. website is hosted at Nginx server. I will see the config file. checked .htaccess file already. it is not causing problem

Comment: @KashifAmin Im facing same issue. what was the solution?